# PDFJS cannot use a local worker file

Tags: javascript, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I'm adding the workerSource
`pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = './pdf.worker.js';`

but still showing this warning in the console **Setting up fake worker.**

It works only when referencing the original file in github

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
```

Comment: perhaps the path is wrong?

Comment: @JaromandaX, I don't think so, I tried a lot of paths but the same result.
Other person have the same issue but I don't know if they fixed it
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/10997

Comment: I take it your local pdf.worker.js is identical to the original file - i.e. same version 2.15.318 - interesting version ... the release is only 2.14.305

Comment: @JaromandaX, thats the thing. First I used the first version  then I replaced the file content with the content of the url //mozilla...

Comment: and they are identical?

Comment: Yes, the same version in both files. I found in another answers that the workerSrc should take a url, So U used the url to my file but still have the same issue.
BTW I'm using only javascript(no React) in a .NET MVC

Comment: `the workerSrc should take a url` well, mine is `"/js/pdf.worker.min.js"` - of course, since the code is running in the browser, that is still a URL - I too had this problem, I'm using an older version (2.5.207) not sure if it was because of this or some other issue though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the issue because I already had an instance of the pdfWorker created when the file pdf.worker.js was loaded,  I fixed it by adding this `globalThis.pdfjsWorker = null;` just before setting the workerSrc
Like this I was  able to create a new instance with the local file

Comment: Maybe you had `import pdfjsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry'` somewhere, which is suggested in some tutorials, but shouldn't be used in combination with setting a custom worker. Importing `pdf.worker.entry` sets the default worker `./pdf.worker.js` already.

Answer (score -2):

If your using webpack to create the build, use the webpack referenced file instead of /pdf.js

`import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack';`

Reference: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/webpack